# Does quickblox provide console for chatting which can be used by the customer care executives

Tags: android, chat, quickblox

I want to use quickblox for chatting integration with an android application for providing shopping assistant services. Does quickblox provides any console which can be used by the customer care executives.

Comment: What do you mean by console? What exactly you want to implement? Please elaborate your request.

Comment: I want to provide shopping assistant to the users for better experience of the android application. So, whenever a user sends a message how can be routed it to customer care executives for sending the response.